# How to build select cmd on rails active model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

**User Table**

```
id| name  | email          | invited_by_id  
1 | jhon  | jhon@mail.com  | null  
2 | sarah | sarah@mail.com | 1  
3 | baby  | baby@mail.com  | 2
```

As User table you'll see sarah's invited by jhon and baby's invited by sarah

**Expect Result**

```
id| name  | email         | invited_by_id | invited_by_name  
1 | jhon  | jhon@mail.com | null          | null  
2 | sarah | sarah@mail.com| 1             | jhon  
3 | baby  | baby@mail.com | 2             | sarah
```

How to create select cmd or best way to get the result as my expect on rails active model ?

Comment: @Zoker,@A Fader Darkly your guide & trick i working and solve this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.rb`

```
def inviter_name
  if self.invited_by_id.nil?
    nil
  else
    User.find(self.invited_by_id).name
  end
end
```

or you can use `belongs_to`

```
belongs_to :inviter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: 'invited_by_id'
```

and the inviter name can be got like below:

```
@user.inviter.name
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zoker is correct, you should add a 'belongs_to' clause to your model definition:

```
belongs_to :invited_by, class_name: "User"
```

Once done, the request could be as simple as this:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  puts [user.name, user.email, user.invited_by_id.to_s, user.invited_by.name].join(", ")
end
```

This will print out a (very) basic CSV list of the results you require. This makes most sense in a console session - if you put this code in a controller you'd end up with it getting lost in the server output.

For large lists you will get a performance hit using this look-up. For each row, a separate request will be made to the database to find the 'invited by' user so we can read the name.

Better is to do this:

```
User.includes(:invited_by).each do |user|
  puts [user.name, user.email, user.invited_by_id.to_s, user.invited_by.name].join(", ")
end
```

This tells Rails to make one more query, which gets all the included 'invited_by' users in one go. This means that instead of making (number_of_rows + 1) queries you're now making just 2.

(Code untested at time of writing.)